# Which algorithms involves in deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

So far I know deep learning is a subset of machine learning. I know some algorithms and it's implementations like KNN, Naive bayes etc in machine learning. Is there any specific set of algorithms to represent and implement deep learning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a common missconception to mix concepts of "algorithm", "method", "model" and "implementation" of particular ML concepts. Most of things defined in ML community is a model or method, not an algorithm or implementation. Roughly speaking:

- **model** is a form of **representing actual, real processes** in the form of mathematical equations/formulas. One of such models can be a nearest neighbour classifier or linear classifier
- **method** is often a **form of approaching the problem** of finding the parameters of a *model* using some data (like for example *gradient methods* of optimization, often used to train ML models)
- **algorithm** is a **set of instructions**, often in some pseudo-code showing the exact operations one needs to do in order to create some *implementation* of a given *method*.
- finally **implementation** is one, particular **piece of code** which realizes some abstract algorithm

So now, **deep learning** is just a general concept in ML, which does not yet have clear definition, although it is often used to relate to **models involving hierarchical abstraction of data representation** as well as **methods of training such models**.

The most common DL models are **deep neural networks**, in other words **neural networks** which have multiple (how many? it is an open debate, some say 5, other 10 or 30) nonlinear hidden layers. Some of the models include:

- Deep Boltzmann Machines (DBM)
- Deep Autoencoder (DAE)
- Deep Convolutional Neural Network (DCNN)
- Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN)

In general **models** can be **deep**, and there can be methods, algorithms **for** deep learning or implementations **of** algorithms **for** deep learning. Some of such algorithms are

- Contrastive Divergence (CD)
- Persistent Constrastive Divergence (PCD)

Which are used to **train DBMs**.

Answer (score 1):

Deep learning is a subset of machine learning inspired by the working of a human brain. It involves training a large number of neurons which build up to make one model and then using this model to predict some new observations. 
Deep learning has two categories of learning which involves various types of models(should not be mentioned as algorithms) as described below:

1. **Supervised Deep Learning:** Learning under supervision i.e. giving a large input and output data set and training the model and then using this trained model to predict output for new observations of data.
   Has primarily three types of deep learning models

***Artificial Neural Networks***: Used for Regression and Classification. Example simple text data.

***Convolutional Neural Networks:*** Used for image classification and computer vision.

***Recurrent Neural Networks:*** Used for Time Series Analysis and Long Short Term Memory. Example translation from one language to another.

2. **Unsupervised Deep Learning:** Learning on their own. Has primarily three types of models :

***Self Organizing Maps:*** Used for feature detection

***Deep Boltzmann Machines:*** Used for recommendation systems

***Auto Encoders:*** Used for recommendation systems

Answer (score 0):

**These below algorithms are involved in deep learning:**

Deep learning then can be defined as neural networks with a large number of parameters and layers in one of four fundamental network architectures.

- Unsupervised Pre-trained Networks.
- Convolutional Neural Networks.
- Recurrent Neural Networks.
- Recursive Neural Networks.